# Logic Editor - only selected objects of Layer 1 are showing

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am using 2.79a RC. (unfortunately also true as far back 2.78a)

Unless all my objects are on Layer 1, there is no way for me to select and view multiple objects in the logic panel.

Is anyone else able to confirm if this is bug or desired behavior? 
And possibly provide a workaround?

This image is all objects in the scene selected. Several of them have logic bricks attached.

[image: logic bricks not showing]

This image is the same file, I just moved everything to Layer 1 with <kbd>M</kbd>

[image: logic bricks showing]

Comment: Are you really sure you want to see the logic of many objects at the same time? Typically I select a single object, that is enough information to see what it is doing.

Comment: @Monster How do you connect sensors on two items to the same AND controller?

Comment: I really try to avoid inter-object connections. Nevertheless I can select one and shift select the second one to show the bricks of both objects. I use layers to temporary remove objects from game or to act as storage for copy templates. In both cases I never needed to connect objects of different layers. So I do not have a use case, but you have. I just tested  (2.79) I do not discover the problems to see the logic bricks of the selected objects in different layers even with the settings of your screen shot. It might be a silly little switch somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried with a brand new blend file? Could it be the selected files are on hidden layers (you can still select them in outliner)?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to select/link objects from layer 1 and 2 for example, both layers must be active.

You can select multiple layers by holding down the `SHIFT` key and selecting individual layers to toggle them on/off.

Use the same `SHIFT` method to select individual objects to link logic-bricks to and fro from the desired objects.